# What is _obj in chai?

Tags: javascript, testing, chai

I know that it's used when building a plugin, but how does it actually work?

From what I can tell, it's the object onto which the assertion is made. Is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the object on which you make the assertion, the "actual" value. But you only have to mind if you're building a plugin. From the [docs](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/plugins/):

> The object flag is the most important of Chai’s reserved flags is the object flag. This is the subject of an assertion.
>
> ```
> var myAssert = new Assertion('Arthur Dent');
> var obj = flag(myAssert, 'object'); // obj === 'Arthur Dent';
> ```

Practically, if can create your own assertion method like this:

```
chai.Assertion.addMethod("myCustomEqual", function(expected) {
  console.log(this._obj); // this._obj = actual value
  console.log(expected); // expected value
  return this.assert(this._obj === expected, `expected ${this._obj} to equal ${expected}`);
});
```

To run the test:

```
it("should pass", function() {
  const j = 10;
  j.should.be.myCustomEqual(10);
});
```